# gcc compiler __SIZE_TYPE__

Tags: c, gcc, size-type

I'm curious about the variable `__SIZE_TYPE__` which is predefined by gcc compiler.

Suppose that I coded like following sentence in C

```
typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t;
```

Is there any possibility that an error occurs when I use another C compiler excluding gcc? 
Do all C compilers have the variable `__SIZE_TYPE__`?

Comment: `SIZE_TYPE` or `__SIZE_TYPE__`? Names starting with double underscore are generally special for a specific "implementation", that is a specific compiler and/or library and are not considered portable.

Comment: All C compilers have `size_t`, unless they're stuck in the nineties. All software written in C uses `size_t`, unless they're stuck in the nineties. Why would you want to use `__SIZE_TYPE__` instead?

Comment: Note that `__SIZE_TYPE__` isn't a variable; it's a type.  Compilers other than GCC probably do not provide it, unless they're trying to be compatible with GCC.  If you want `size_t`, include `<stddef.h>` if you aren't including any of the other headers (such as `<stdio.h>`, `<string.h>`, `<stdlib.h>` — the mighty trio) that also define it.

Comment: @Rhymoid: most compilers from the 90s have `size_t`; it was part of C89/C90, after all.  Only compilers stuck in the 80s might not have `size_t`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler if only I wasn't stuck with a 80s compiler `gcc version 11.1.0` and it had `size_t` type without including headers that pull in a bunch of spaghetti with `typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t` somewhere in there and `int main() { size_t a; }` just compiled... :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible that an error occurs as soon as you use any identifier with double underscore. See the C standard 7.1.3:

> All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase
>   letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.

As for `__SIZE_TYPE__` that's apparently a gcc identifier. I don't think any other compiler uses it, but there are no guarantees. Another compiler is perfectly free to use the same identifier *even for an entirely different purpose*.

Comment: It appears to be a typedef for unsigned long anyway https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3aa439PEr