# Use of sizeof operator in C

Tags: c, sizeof

I wrote a code to print size of different data types in C .

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
     printf("%d", sizeof(int));//size of integer
     printf("%d", sizeof(float));
     printf("%d", sizeof(double));
     printf("%d", sizeof(char));
}
```

This does not work , but if I replace `%d` with `%ld`, it works. I did not understand why I have to take `long int` to print a small range number.

Comment: Which compiler / platform? I think it will work in most cases. It is better to add `\n` after `%d` like `printf("%d\n", sizeof...);`

Comment: "This does not work". Exactly, how does it not work. Show your steps to reproduce your problem.

Comment: it was giving compile error but I got the answer with %zu !

Comment: @parasghai: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 9):

Both of those are wrong you must use `%zu` to print values of type `size_t`, which is what `sizeof` return.

This is because different values have different size, and you must match them.

It's undefined behavior to mismatch like you do, so anything could happen.

Comment: If the OP is using MS Visual Studio and for completeness: MS Visual Studio didn't support `%zu` printf specifier before VS2013. Starting from VS2013 (e.g. `_MSC_VER >= 1800`) `%zu` is finally available. So casting like the other answer would be an option if `%zu` isn't available.

Answer (score 3):

This is because sizes mismatch. By either using `%zu` or using `%u` and casting to `unsigned` you may fix the problem.

Currently, your implementation is undefined behaviour.

```
 printf("%u", (unsigned)sizeof(int));//size of integer
 printf("%u", (unsigned)sizeof(float));
 printf("%u", (unsigned)sizeof(double));
 printf("%u", (unsigned)sizeof(char));
```

Since `stdout` is new line buffered, don't forget to print `\n` at the end to get anything to screen.

Comment: `\n` is a good idea, yet output like `"4481\n"` would benefit with additional spacing.  Detail: it is because the types do not match.

Comment: sorry, _`stdout` is line buffered_ is not exact.  Stdio actually checks if the descriptor is associated with a tty device by making a `ioctl(2)` system call (normally as a result of a `isatty(3)` call, and if that is true, it switches to line buffering.  Else, full buffering is done. There's an alternative, calling `fflush(3)` on `stdout`, after the last `printf(3)` call.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` has the return type `size_t`.  From the Standard,

```
6.5.3.4  The sizeof and _Alignof operators
```

> 5 The  value  of  the  result  of  both  operators  is 
>   implementation-deﬁned,  and  its  type  (an unsigned integer type) is
>   size_t, deﬁned in `<stddef.h>` (and other headers).

`size_t` is implementation-defined.  In my linux, size_t is defined as `__SIZE_TYPE__`. On this topic, one can find details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36857141/gcc-compiler-size-type).

In your case, it happens that size_t is implemented as a long , longer than `int`.

Comment: OP's `size_t` is probably `unsigned long`, but not a `long`, since `size_t` must be an `unsigned` integer type.

Comment: @DavidBowling, I think so, by the type size matters, as I do not think the sign will influence the behaviour of printf for such a small value.

Comment: Since the small values are representable as a signed and unsigned integer, C11 §6.5.2.2 6 applies.  `scanf()` does not "know" if it received a signed or unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

> I did not understand why I have to take long int to print a small range number.

Because `size_t` may represent values much larger than what an `int` can support; on my particular implementation, the max size value is `18446744073709551615`, which *definitely* won't fit in an `int`.

Remember that the operand of `sizeof` may be a parenthesized type name *or* an object expression:

```
static long double really_big_array[100000000];
...
printf( "sizeof really_big_array = %zu\n", sizeof really_big_array );
```

`size_t` must be able to represent the size of the largest object the implementation allows.

Answer (score 0):

You say *it does not work*, but you do not say what it does. The most probable reason for this unexpected behavior is:

- the conversion specifier `%d` expects an `int` value. `sizeof(int)` has type `size_t` which is unsigned and, on many platforms, larger than `int`, causing undefined behavior.

The conversion specifier and the type of the passed argument must be consistent because different types are passed in different ways to a vararg function like `printf()`.  If you pass a `size_t` and `printf` expects an `int`, it will retrieve the value from the wrong place and produce inconsistent output if at all.

You say *it works if I put `%ld`*.  This conversion may work because `size_t` happens to have the same size as `long` for your platform, but it is only a coincidence, on 64-bit Windows, `size_t` is larger than `long`.

To correct the problem, you can either:

- use the standard conversion specifier `%zu` or
- cast the value as `int`.

The first is the correct fix but some C libraries do not support `%zu`, most notably Microsoft C runtime libraries prior to VS2013.  Hence I recommend the second as more portable and sufficient for types and objects that obviously have a small size:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(int));
    printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(float));
    printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(double));
    printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(char));
    return 0;
}
```

Also note that you do not output a newline:  Depending on the environment, the output will not be visible to the user until a newline is output or `fflush(stdout)` is called. It is even possible that the output not be flushed to the console upon program exit, causing your observed behavior, but such environments are uncommon. It is recommended to output newlines at the end of meaningful pieces of output. In your case, not doing so would cause all sizes to be clumped together as a sequence of digits like `4481`, which may or may not be what you expect.

Comment: hahahaha... well... then I concede also and shall take off  my comment of he way :)